# How to exclude covariates of a Cox model?

Tags: spss, cox-model

I am using the Cox regression model to forecast failures of machines. I have several possible covariates. I ran the analysis in SPSS. The method I used to add covariates was backward stepwise (Wald).

My question is that after I got the results, which is the table 'Variables in the Equation' (see below), I can see that some covariates are not significant: for example, Cate and PCPT are not significant.

Can I still use this solution? I mean excluding the ones which are not significant, but keep the rest, and use the coefficients $\exp(B)$ for the other covariates in the Cox regression equation $h(t)=h_0(t)\exp(zx)$?

Or I should exclude these two non-significant covariates when I add them to SPSS and get a new solution in which all the covariates are significant?

Variables in the Equation

```
          B     SE   Wald df  Sig. Exp(B)
ACT     -.004 .001 31.814  1 .000   .996
TPCPT    .002 .001  6.287  1 .012  1.002
ALT      .008 .001 31.046  1 .000  1.008
MALTCPT 1.315 .204 41.465  1 .000  3.723
LTCPT   2.101 .592 12.601  1 .000  8.176
Cate     .076 .046  2.743  1 .098  1.079
PCPT     .004 .002  3.611  1 .057  1.004
```

Comment: How exactly are you creating forecasts from this model? Are you using smoothing spline estimates of the Schoenfeld residuals to estimate the baseline hazard function? If so, do you do this *before* or *after* eliminating "insignificant" variables? If your goal is prediction, some very prognostic markers may have inference on hazards ratios which are not significant.

Comment: The baseline hazard is usually estimated by the more straightforward Breslow or Kalbfleisch-Prentice methods.

Answer (score 2):

It is not statistically correct to remove "insignificant" variables, just as stepwise regression (without penalization) is invalid.  Much has been written about this topic.

Comment: I used Breslow method to get the estimated baseline hazard. But for my question, if it is not statistically correct to remove insignificant variables, what can I do here? Just to accept this solution which contains some insignificant covariates? Can you give me some references addressing my problem?

Comment: What about having insignificant variables in a model makes you uncomfortable?  If you are doing an ANOVA on 5 groups do you collapse groups that are not "significant"?